# How do I create a checkered material where the black parts are glass and the white are diffuse

Tags: materials

I am trying to create a material for a place that is like the checker texture but i want the black parts to be glass and the white parts to be diffuse.
Can i do this in blender ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the node editor, add a mix shader node. You can then plug in a black and white checker texture into the fac and your glass and diffuse shader into the other two. Just switch the diffuse and glass shader to switch which way around you want the shaders.

Good luck with your project and I hope I helped,

BFB

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add a pic so it is clear for others
[image]